# Variance of first 30 odd numbers

Tags: statistics

How to calculate variance of first 30 odd numbers ?

The method I used requires finding the mean and subtracting each number with it and then squaring the result . Its getting difficult .
  I used this :

[image: this]

Any other way to calculate ?

Comment: Your method's not too difficult, you just need to know the formulae for sum of squares and such.

Comment: You can use variance = E(x^2) - [ E(x) ]^2. Computing the last two os only using whole numbers, but a division by n.

Comment: The mean is exactly 30.

Comment: Sorry , confused it with another question .

Comment: @coffeemath E is expectation ?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I deleted it .

Answer (score 3):

The first 30 odd numbers don't have variance. The uniform distribution over the first 30 odd numbers has variance, given by
$$
\frac{1}{30} \sum_{i=0}^{29} (2i+1)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{30} \sum_{i=0}^{29} (2i+1)\right)^2 = \frac{899}{3}.
$$
More generally, one calculates that the variance of the uniform distribution over the first $n$ odd numbers is $$ \frac{n^2-1}{3}. $$

Comment: Is this a formula?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gmxAWSW I use this

Comment: I calculated this using a program, since that was faster and less error-prone than using a formula in this case. But formulas also exist.

Comment: But which formula did you apply ? The above eqn doesnt fall into the formula I linked

Comment: I applied the formula $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Comment: Is E expectation?

Comment: Yes. ~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: But that comes in Probability

Comment: You can also use your own formula. You'll get the same result.

Comment: But that is too lenghty , I wanted an easier way .

Comment: There are no shortcuts in life.

Comment: Too bad, then..